# What does "variability" mean in statistics?

Tags: statistics

I'm using an introductory statistics textbook and it mentioned this:

"Describing the data with reference to the spread is called "variability". The variability in data depends upon the method by which the outcomes are obtained; for example, by measuring or by random sampling"

Comment: Welcome to Mathematics Stack Exchange.  Roughly speaking, variability tells how much the data points are spread from the mean

Comment: Thank you so much!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Welcome to Mathematics Stack Exchange.

Roughly speaking, in statistics, variability tells how much the data points are spread from the mean.